# Let $x_1,x_2,\dots ,x_{50}$ be $50$ integers such that the sum of any $6$ of them is 24, then:

Tags: contest-math

Let $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{50}$ be $50$ integers such that the sum of any $6$ of them is $24$, then which option is true

1. the largest of $x_i$ equals $6$.
2. the smallest of $x_i$ equals $3$.
3. $x_{16}=x_{34}$.

I am totally clueless how to proceed :(

Help appreciated :)

Comment: $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_7\implies x_6=x_7$.  Can you take it from there?

Comment: Pretty good rating please use latex

Comment: This question would make more sense if it asked for consecutive $6$ of them

Comment: As another way to see it, the sum of the six greatest elements is the same as the sum of the six smallest, which gives the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key part is that the sum of $\textbf{any}$ $6$ of the numbers must be $24$. Therefore, $$x_1=x_2=\dots=x_{50}=4$$